# Is it possible for github to remove my email adress from public repositories from a purely technical standpoint?

Tags: github, git-rewrite-history

On GitHub, I contributed to Free/Libre & Open Source projects. Now, *I want my email address from those commits to be removed*.
I expect my user name to be in those commits, too. It does contain my surname and initial of my given at least. Some commits might even contain my full name.

*I do expect GDPR to treat the combination of email address and personal name as goods protected in its scope*. GDPR does state that the storage of personal data has to happen in consent and with a limited time frame.
(About the latter, I guess I will have to disable the auto-enabled option to "store my data for future generations in an arctic vault", but let's discuss that at another time.)

It would be cumbersome to *write to each maintained repository*.
Most of the times, *they even have 10+ forks with no commit activity* by those users which happen to share the information visibly. (GitHub does sometimes enforce public forks via an option, which at least works for lazy "fork-button-clickers".)

*Therefore*, I do not actually expect to get my personal data completely removed even if I put in a lot of manual work.

From a technical standpoint, git history has to be rewritten. Every DVCS user has to accept those changes [1].

Legally speaking,the case is clear. But:
Is it feasible with the help of GitHub to enforce my right to privacy in many projects? Would published NPM modules be affected as well? (I expect to have only changed their documentation, not actual executable scripts. But exactly the documentation is often hyperlinked to at github from npm.)

**It would require all public repositories to accept such a change of history**, and perhaps even put in the work to bulk-remove the mail address?

### EDIT:

Accepted answer: GitHub can change these Projects and all Forks to private. Works for me, but would hurt these open source projects as well.

The effort to auto-rewrite history (via a script/programming) seems to be out of scope for such an infrequent request.

TY. I do regret asking too broadly and not about recent historical examples.

---

[1]: What I do not expect is, that every user will purge my email address from their private repositories. My problem is with the easy accessibility of my email address to web scrapers at a central location.

Comment: `On GitHub, I contributed to FLOSS projects. Now, I want my email address from those commits to be removed.` - ok, good luck with that.

Comment: I mean, "from a purely technical standpoint", it is possible for GitHub to replace any combination of bits in their database with any other combination of bits, so yes, they could delete every instance of your name and email from every repo.  Would it be a lot of work for them?  Sure.  Would it break a lot of stuff? Probably. Are they going to do it on your request?  I doubt it.  Are you correct in your assertion that they legally required to do it?  Off topic for this site.

Comment: @NateEldredge I expect *them* to be only required to do so, if it would be appropriate to ask that amount of work for a given amount of privacy gain. That is why I would like to know the amount of work-in-question before asking a law-stackexchange question or the local "Landesdatenschutzbeauftragen", i.e. our german office for privacy (and open government data).

Also, who is *them* in that sentence has to be clear before I ask anyone to do anything. For now, i woudl suggest GitHub and watch you stackers' argue me out of it or bring up examples of when that actually worked.

Comment: Github offers an option to commit with an anonimized email address. https://github.blog/2017-04-11-private-emails-now-more-private/

Comment: @jessehouwing going forward, that solves the problem. My problem is with commits in the past, dug deep in the history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub stores repositories, so from a purely technical standpoint, they are physically capable of editing the data to change it in any way, shape, or form.  This is true of literally anybody who stores data on a standard storage medium.

However, because GitHub retains relatively few legal rights to host repositories, they won't modify repositories without the consent of the owner.  If there's a legal challenge, they just disable the access to the repository; they don't edit it in any way.  The issue of whether your data can and should be removed is left to the project maintainers.  As a result, there's no tooling for GitHub to modify any repositories in any way outside of the normal permissions model, and sending any sort of request, legal or otherwise, won't be effective in getting your data actually removed.

I am of course not a lawyer and nothing I say is legal advice, and if you have questions about the law, you should contact an attorney licensed in your jurisdiction.  However, you should note that projects that use the Developer's Certificate of Origin (such as Linux and Git) explicitly require you to assent to the recording of your personal information for the life of the project, and if you've signed off your commit, you've made a legal statement agreeing to that, which people may rely on in good faith.  If you cannot make a binding statement to that effect in your jurisdiction, then as a consequence the only legal thing would be to refrain from contributing at all.

Comment: TY for the insight. Disabling access would hurt these open source projects.

About giving a lifelong copyright or data privacy consent: that seems valid in common law. For now I could live with that. But the repositories in question did not have me sign a committer's agreement, which of course could change legal matters. This question should be about the technical feasability, if I can manage to not go astray myself here...
In germany, I don't think that giving rights to a third party is irrevocable per se. If the circumstances change, you may get to revoke personal information, especially.